# Vertex AI/Kubeflow Pipelines, ModelBatchPredictOp Does Not Take Outputs of Previous Components

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, kubeflow-pipelines

The title of this question is self-explanatory.

If I have a Kubeflow pipeline in the following manner:

```
# this is a kubeflow pipelines component dedicated to reformatting csv data to jsonl format
reformat_input_op = reformat_input_component(test_path)

# connect reformat prediction inputs op to batch prediction op
batch_prediction_request_jsonl_path = reformat_input_op.outputs['Batch Prediction Input GCS Path']
    
# batch prediction op
batch_prediction_op = gcc_aip.ModelBatchPredictOp(
        project="<project id>", 
        job_display_name="Model Batch Prediction", 
        location="us-west1", 
        model=model_output, 
        gcs_source_uris=[batch_prediction_request_jsonl_path], 
        instances_format="jsonl",
        gcs_destination_output_uri_prefix="gs://<bucket name>/<directory to file output>/",
        machine_type="n1-standard-4", 
        accelerator_count=2, 
        accelerator_type="NVIDIA_TESLA_P100")
```

The `ModelBatchPredictOp` method's argument, `gcs_source_uris` cannot ingest the output of the previous component that outputs a string path (I get a `TypeError: Object of type PipelineParam is not JSON serializable` error).

This is troublesome because I do not want to hardcode the path to the GCS bucket that the previous component writes to. I want the path that the previous component outputs, inputted into the next component, at runtime.

What are some workarounds to this? While this is somewhat of a duplicate question to this stackoverflow query: [Vertex AI Model Batch prediction, issue with referencing existing model and input file on Cloud Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70356856/vertex-ai-model-batch-prediction-issue-with-referencing-existing-model-and-inpu)

I feel as if the question was not clearly answered there. Is there a way to pass an input from a previous component directly into the `ModelBatchPredictOp()` object?

Note: I do not want an answer saying "use the `.after()` method on the `ModelBatchPredictOp()`". I know this is an option, I don't understand why `ModelBatchPredictOp()`, a Kubeflow Pipeline component, doesn't admit outputs of the previous components directly. And is there a way that I can pass the output of a previous component directly without storing to some other GCS path and then calling it after using `.after()`? This is horrible design if there's no way to pass the outputs of the previous components directly.

Comment: Could you try `gcs_source_uris=f’s://{BUCKET_NAME}/….’` instead of `gcs_source_uris=[batch_prediction_request_jsonl_path]` ?